# как разобрать API json ответ с записью в csv в Python

Tags: python, json, csv

Подскажите в каком направлении копать, изучать Python чтоб решить такую проблему. Есть json ответ по чемпионату Франции по футболу за сезон. Как с него вытаскивать дату матча, название команд и счёт матча и первого тайма.
{
"errors": [],
"get": "fixtures",
"paging": {
"current": 1,
"total": 1
},
"parameters": {
"league": "61",
"season": "2023"
},
"response": [
{
"fixture": {
"date": "2023-08-12T19:00:00+00:00",
"id": 1044881,
"periods": {
"first": 1691866800,
"second": 1691870400
},
"referee": "B. Dechepy",
"status": {
"elapsed": 90,
"long": "Match Finished",
"short": "FT"
},
"timestamp": 1691866800,
"timezone": "UTC",
"venue": {
"city": "Paris",
"id": 671,
"name": "Parc des Princes"
}
},
"goals": {
"away": 0,
"home": 0
},
"league": {
"country": "France",
"flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/fr.svg",
"id": 61,
"logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/61.png",
"name": "Ligue 1",
"round": "Regular Season - 1",
"season": 2023
},
"score": {
"extratime": {
"away": null,
"home": null
},
"fulltime": {
"away": 0,
"home": 0
},
"halftime": {
"away": 0,
"home": 0
},
"penalty": {
"away": null,
"home": null
}
},
"teams": {
"away": {
"id": 97,
"logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/97.png",
"name": "Lorient",
"winner": null
},
"home": {
"id": 85,
"logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/85.png",
"name": "Paris Saint Germain",
"winner": null
}
}
},
{
"fixture": {
"date": "2023-08-13T18:45:00+00:00",
"id": 1044882,
"periods": {
"first": 1691952300,
"second": 1691955900
},
"referee": "J. Brisard",
"status": {
"elapsed": 90,
"long": "Match Finished",
"short": "FT"
},
"timestamp": 1691952300,
"timezone": "UTC",
"venue": {
"city": "Strasbourg",
"id": 681,
"name": "Stade de la Meinau"
}
},
"goals": {
"away": 1,
"home": 2
},
"league": {
"country": "France",
"flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/fr.svg",
"id": 61,
"logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/61.png",
"name": "Ligue 1",
"round": "Regular Season - 1",
"season": 2023
},
"score": {
"extratime": {
"away": null,
"home": null
},
"fulltime": {
"away": 1,
"home": 2
},
"halftime": {
"away": 0,
"home": 0
},
"penalty": {
"away": null,
"home": null
}
},
"teams": {
"away": {
"id": 80,
"logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/80.png",
"name": "Lyon",
"winner": false
},
"home": {
"id": 95,
"logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/95.png",
"name": "Strasbourg",
"winner": true
}
}
}

Comment: В направлении как работать с json. Очевидно же, не?